# Pushing a Qualcomm Vuforia viewcontroller, can't import header file

Tags: objective-c, ios, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I have a UIViewController pushed onto a UINavigationController as the rootViewController and when a button is touched I want to push the Vuforia ImageTarget's example viewcontroller.

To do that I need to alloc/init the Vuforia's viewcontroller within an IBAction method in my UIViewController but I can't import "QCARutils.h" and "ARParentViewController.h" I seem to get lots of completely unrelated errors.

First error I get is within Matrices.h : " Unknown type name 'namespace' "

I'm assuming this is some library linking issue, I just can't for the life of me find out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your .m files to .mm files. QCAR is C++, and .mm extension tells Xcode to compile this file as Objective C++.

Comment: Kreiri, that seemed to work, magically! However, I don't believe changing my view controller to a .mm is the correct answer to what I want to do. Is there a more "correct" way to do this?